# DMLException.getDmlFields Fails When Inserting List of SObjects?

Tags: apex, dmlexception, sobjectfield

When a DML operation on a list of records of a concrete object type, e.g. `Account` fails, calling `getDmlFields` on the thrown `DMLException` returns the fields that caused the failure, as described in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm).

But when a DML operation on a `List<SObject>` fails, `getDmlFields` returns null.

Here's an example:

```
force apex <<EOF
try {
   insert new List<Account>{new Account()};
} catch (DMLException e) {
   for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
      System.debug('FAILED INSERTING ACCOUNT');
      System.debug('ERROR FIELD NAMES');
      System.debug(e.getDmlFieldNames(i));
      System.debug('ERROR FIELDS');
      System.debug(e.getDmlFields(i));
   }
}
try {
   insert new List<SObject>{new Account()};
} catch (DMLException e) {
   for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
      System.debug('FAILED INSERTING SOBJECT');
      System.debug('ERROR FIELD NAMES');
      System.debug(e.getDmlFieldNames(i));
      System.debug('ERROR FIELDS');
      System.debug(e.getDmlFields(i));
   }
}
EOF
```

In both cases, a validation rule on the `Type` field causes the insert to fail.  The call to `getDmlFieldNames` returns `Type` in both cases, but in the second case, the call to `getDmlFields` returns null.

```
15:41:36.15 (39209292)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Account:new
15:41:36.15 (39398837)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Account:new
15:41:36.15 (40276287)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[2]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Type is required for Referral Accounts: [Type]
15:41:36.15 (40838118)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|FAILED INSERTING ACCOUNT
15:41:36.15 (40861711)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|ERROR FIELD NAMES
15:41:36.15 (40965320)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|(Type)
15:41:36.15 (40987483)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|ERROR FIELDS
15:41:36.15 (41104191)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|(Type)
15:41:36.15 (43357699)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Account:new
15:41:36.15 (43515984)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Account:new
15:41:36.15 (44175767)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[13]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Type is required for Referral Accounts: [Type]
15:41:36.15 (44572412)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|FAILED INSERTING SOBJECT
15:41:36.15 (44591105)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|ERROR FIELD NAMES
15:41:36.15 (44656270)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|(Type)
15:41:36.15 (44676099)|USER_DEBUG|[19]|DEBUG|ERROR FIELDS
15:41:36.15 (44719764)|USER_DEBUG|[20]|DEBUG|null
```

Is this expected behavior or a Salesforce bug?

Comment: Interesting question. Funny thing is, I tried to replicate, but even the first case (the one typed to Account) is not returning any values for `getDmlFields` or `getDmlFieldNames`. Puzzling...

Comment: @mkorman, what error do you get?  (My example used a custom validation rule.)

Comment: I created a validation rule as well (Name must be longer than 10 characters). I got a DML exception; however, when I printed the contents of `getDmlFields` and names, there was just 1 row, with blank/null values.

Comment: Did you configure the Error Location to show the error on the Name field?  I'm seeing the same behavior with a validation rule on Name as on Type.

Answer (score 2):

According to support, this is as designed, although it seems more like an oversight than a design decision to me.  In any case, it should be documented.

From support:

> The behavior that we see when we are using List is working as
>   designed. Please find the  detailed summary for the same below
>
> -- The getDMLFieldName's return type is String[] whereas getDMLFields return type is Schema.sObjectField[]
>
> which means the getDMLFields has to make a describe call to get the
>   fields. The describe call looks something like follows
>
> Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
>
> We need concrete SObject Types like Account or Opportunity to get this
>   Describe call working. As Heterogeneous list List cannot be
>   used to get the instance and map it to the describe call.
>
> Hence kindly use Homogeneous List types like List or
>   List to get the getDMLFields() working.

As a work-around, you can get the `SObjectField` if you keep a reference to the list of SObjects on which the failed DML operation was performed.

```
List<SObject> sobjects = new List<SObject>{new Account()};
try {
   insert sobjects;
} catch (DMLException e) {
  for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
    // Get the list of field names, which may not be globally unique,
    // but will be unique for a single SObject
    List<String> fieldNames = e.getDmlFieldNames(i);
    // Get the SObjectType for the record that failed
    Integer insertIndex = e.getDmlIndex(i);
    Schema.SObjectType failedType =   sobjects[insertIndex].getSObjectType();
    for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
      // Use the field name to get the SObjectField
      Schema.SObjectField fieldFromName = failedType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName);
      System.debug('SOBJECT FIELD FROM NAME');
      System.debug(fieldFromName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to quote support directly?

Comment: "We believe that its working as designed and it has to do with describe call while access metadata. However I am discussing this case with our Internal Team for some concrete information based on which we can identify the behavior of DMLException.getDmlFields when we use <sobject>."  I'll update the answer here if I get a better solution than my work-around from support.